# Getting the browser to save a downloaded file

Tags: java, http, browser, download

I am working with an app to learn JavaEE file handling

I am using Netbeans 8.0.1, Wildfly 8, JPA and  Primefaces.

I have only one objet with 4 properties

@Id @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_articulo;

```
private String titulo;

private String descripcion;


@Lob
private File archivo;

I made a form to upload data including the file as a blob, the form call a method in a backing bean




public void generarArticulo() throws IOException{


        File destFile= new File(fichero.getFileName());
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fichero.getInputstream(), destFile);

        articulo a = new articulo();
        a.setArchivo(destFile);
        a.setTitulo(titulo);
        a.setDescripcion(descripcion);


        this.controlador.registrarArticulo(a);

    }
```

This method works fine, the record is added to the database

Then I also made a datatable, it works fine and it shows every record in the database,also to test that every file is being retrieved I use a outputtext that gives me the weight in bytes of every file, and it does it well

```
<p:dataTable var="articulos" value="#{listadoArticulos.listado}" 
                         rows="10"
                         paginator="true"
                         >
                    <p:column headerText="Titulo" sortBy="#{articulos.titulo}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{articulos.titulo}"  />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descripcion" >
        <h:outputText value="#{articulos.descripcion}" />
    </p:column>
  [B]<p:column headerText="Fichero" >
      <h:outputText value="#{articulos.archivo.name} y pesa #{articulos.archivo.length()}"  />
    </p:column>[/B]

          <p:column headerText="Descarga">
              <p:commandLink action="#{articuloBean.getFichero(articulos.archivo)}" value="Descargar"/>

    </p:column>          

</p:dataTable>
```

NOw my challenge is to make the user download directly the file from the object in the memory, I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work,
.

The last thing I did was a method getFile(File file) that you can see in the above CommandLInk that calls the following method

```
 public FileOutputStream getFichero (File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

       FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream (file);
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/home/alex/ficheros/"+file.getName());
       int c;

       while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }

       return out;

        }
```

THat method brings me from the database the file storaged and copies it in the folder /home/alex/files, what I want to do is to make this method to download normaly the file allocated in the objects file property directly

ANy idea?

Comment: You can't use  `FileInputStream` on a Blob in a database. The code you have posted has nothing to do with Blobs or databases. A file is found in a file system, not in a database. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am not using  FileInputStream to upload a BLOB I need to download it, both codes seems to work in my server :( The first code allows me to register a new record in my database, that works 100% fine, I just add the record, pick the file.jpg in my HDD and upload it perfectly. Then I can delete from my HDD the file.jpg, go to the datatable where I can check all my records, use the second method and VOILA I have the image back in other directory, what I want is to have it download it in the browser.

Comment: The first code just uploads a file. You haven't shown the part where it becomes a Blob, so it is impossible to advise you on how to get the Blob out again. But you claim that the second piece of code works perfectly, so either you've solved that problem offline, or it doesn't exist. Your question seems to have nothing to do with Blobs or databases at all, but with how to get the browser to dispose of the content as a file. And the answer to that is the Content-Disposition header. You haven't helped yourself by introducing all this extraneous matter and mistitling your question.

Comment: Trust me, the code that uploads the blob   works perfectly, I can see everything in my database, the second code does not do what I want, the second code just copy my BLOB to a folder, what I want to do is NOT to copy it to a specific folder but instead to show the user a normal download dialog in the browser. (My english is not good enought)

Comment: The blob is uploaded by this method   
    public void generarArticulo() throws IOException{
     
  
        File destFile= new File(fichero.getFileName());
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fichero.getInputstream(), destFile);
       
        articulo a = new articulo();
        a.setArchivo(destFile);
        a.setTitulo(titulo);
        a.setDescripcion(descripcion);
        
       
        this.controlador.registrarArticulo(a);
        
    }

Comment: There is no database and no blob in that code. That code just copies one file to another. You're not making any sense. Please clarify your question. Or have I already answered it?

Comment: Ok, forget the code, just think in this, you have a database with a table that has only the ID (integer), the title (string) and a file (BLOB), I have a form that records data in that database (the code works), I have a backing bean that gets me the collection of articles, I can view every object of it and ALL the data is there, so I have a collection of object with a field "file" I need to code a method to download the content of the file as a normal browser download

Comment: No you did not :( , I just delete the entire post and rewrite it completely, I hope to have expressed myself better this time :(

Comment: I repeat: 'the answer to that is the Content-Disposition header.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solve the thing

```
@WebServlet("/DownloadFileServlet")
public class DownloadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    ArticuloControlador controlador;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String x=request.getParameter("x");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(x);

        articulo a = controlador.getArticuloporID(id);
        File f = a.getArchivo();

        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(f);

        String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        System.out.println("relativePath = " + relativePath);

        // obtengo ServletContext
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        // obtengo MIME del fichero
       String mimeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName());

        if (mimeType == null) {        
            // steamos el MIME type si no lo encontramos
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

        // modificamos el response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) f.length());

        // Descargamos
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", f.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);


        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();     
    }
}
```